# How to use .date() from the query performed earlier in django?

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I am writing a django application where I have to get data using date part of a datetimefield as a part of result of a query stored in a variable. Here is my code:

```
datas = Model1.objects.all()

for data in datas:
    new_data = Model2.objects.get(date = data.datetime.date())
```

Model1 has a field called datetime which is a datetimefield and Model2 has a field called date which is a datefield. When I run the server, this is the error I get:

> self.model._meta.object_name data.models.DoesNotExist: Model2 matching
>   query does not exist.

I am guessing `date = data.datetime.date()` is what is causing this. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: If `Model1` has a field `datetime`, then there is nothing wrong with doing `data.datetime.date()`. The error simply means that there are not any model2 objects in your database with that date.

Comment: Ah yes! that's it, sorry, it was a stupid question, i had mixed if else statements. Thanks anyways!